# Can get XML but JSON chucks out 500

Tags: spring, jersey

Spring 5 & Jersey 2

The error:

```
SEVERE [http-apr-9090-exec-2] org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<com.org.schema.common.SomeObject>
```

There aren't any stack traces available.

Note that if I use a different call with the same service and retrieve a single `SomeObject` by ID, I still get a 500 but I don't see any exceptions or errors at all.

I think maybe this might be about a missing dependency. The POM has several exclusions due to a version conflict but I've already found some missing.

Comment: There might be some dependency conflict, because it clearly says " I cannot provide json output"

Answer (score 0):

Here I share a similar exception I had.

The context:

- I am working with pure jersey
- My exception happened on an HTTP response
- My solution - use a different method for writing the body

**The exception:**

```
22-Feb-2018 05:49:55.809 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-22] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write A message body writer for Java class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream, and Java type class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
```

**The code that caused it:**

```
    @Override
public void writeTo(User user, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                    MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
                    OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    ...
    ...
    Writer writer = new PrintWriter(out);
    writer.write("...");
    ...
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}


return Response.ok(streamingOutput, MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf")).header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=price.pdf").build();
```

**My solution**

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream pdfStream = ...                

StreamingOutput streamingOutput = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        pdfStream.writeTo(outputStream);
        pdfStream.flush();
        pdfStream.close();
    }
};

return Response.ok(streamingOutput, MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf")).build();
```

I decided to respond because the error is almost the same, so - I hope this give you an idea where your solution can go, or help you to discard some cases.